# Predictor(AB2)-Corrector(AM2) Method to Solve One-Body Problem

Tags: numerical-methods

I have the following problem. Let,
$$x''(t)=- \frac{3x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$y''(t)=- \frac{3y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$x(0)=0, y(0)=2, x'(0)=1, y'(0)=0$$
I need to use the PC method to solve the problem. I know I need to get the ode above into a system of 1st order ODEs. To do this say:

\begin{align}
x_1 &\equiv x, \\
x_2 &\equiv x_1', \\
y_1 &\equiv y, \\
y_2 &\equiv y_1'.
\end{align}

So the system system will consist of 4, first order, coupled ODEs in 4 variables. It will look like the following
\begin{align}
x_1' &= x_2, \\
x_2' &= \frac{-3x_1}{\left( x_1^2 + y_1^2 \right)^{3/2}}, \\
y_1' &= y_2, \\ 
y_2' &= \frac{-3y_1}{\left( x_1^2 + y_1^2 \right)^{3/2}}.
\end{align}

I also know that I'll need the  solution at the first time step which I can generate using forward Euler. I'm getting my initial condition vector to be $z_0=[0, 2, 1, 0]^T$ and based on my system I'm getting $f_0=[2, 0, 0, 3]^T$. So with h=.01 FE gives a the approximation $z_1 =[.01, 2, 1, -.015]^T$.

Ok so now I need to use the predictor corrector scheme:

Predictor: $z_{i+1}^P=z_i+.005(3f_i-f_{i-1})$

Corrector: $z_{i+1}^c=z_i+.005(f_{i+1}^p+f_i)$

So, $z_{2}^p=z_1+.005(3f_1-f_0)$. I have $z_1$ and $f_0$ from the previous step. To get $f_1$ do I evaluate the system of odes using $z_1$?

Comment: Isn't the initial condition $[0,1,2,0]^T $, which of course will change $f _0$? Otherwise it looks OK.

Comment: Perhaps you should label your notation, because you seem to be switching back and forth between orders of variables and getting confused in the process. Recast the system as you have, with the vector variable being $z=[x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2]^T$. Then $z(0)=[0,1,2,0]^T$, so $z'(0)=\left [1,0,0,-\frac{6}{8} \right ]^T$.

Comment: Thanks that makes life easier.

Comment: I'm curious now, where does the predictor-corrector scheme you are using come from? The main predictor-corrector schemes that I know of basically follow the tangential direction of a curve for a certain distance, then try to find their way back to the curve along the orthogonal directions. In certain contexts this is called arclength continuation. Proceeding this way you are more or less guaranteed conservation of energy; more precisely, the change in the energy will be driven by the convergence tolerance in the corrector algorithm, so it will not accumulate over time.

Comment: So the scheme is made of two linear multistep methods the predictor is the adams bashforth 2 step and the corrector is the adams moulton 2 step method. They still use the tangential approximation to generate the solution.